# Fatal error Mage_Shipping_Model Config.php on line 121

Tags: shipping, error, backend

My store has this error on the shipping page, and it disables my ability to ship the product.  I tried disabling the modules related to shipping, and nothing happens.

Fatal error:  Call to a member function setId() on a non-object in /public_html/includes/src/Mage_Shipping_Model_Config.php on line 121

Is there a way to fix this?  I even tried reinstalling magento (didn’t clear the DB though), and still no luck.  Here’s what my shipping page looks like, the bottom doesn’t look like the html has been read: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lvzwB.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You are using the compiler (generally you shouldn't; opcode caching is generally preferable).
2. Based on the error location I'm going to assume that you have some configuration somewhere (possibly cached) which is declaring an active carrier.

Comment: how should I fix this?  Should I just disable compiler?

Comment: I disabled the compiler and flushed the cache...fixed!  thanks!